# ASP.NET MVC 2: Odd Error

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

The only difference I can think between a project that WAS working to now this new project that's NOT working is the fact that one may have been a normal MVC 2 project whereas this new one is an Empty MVC 2 project.

I'm unaware of the differences other than some helper files... nevertheless, I get this error and I'm at a loss as to what causes it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm just guessing here, but are you sure you have **A)** a connection string in your web config **B)** or that the connection string is named appropriatelly. For example, LINQ to SQL will name its connection string as the name of the context, so in your case something like `SalesConnectionString`.

Comment: I thought there was hope, but alas, no... my connection string name is correct. And I've tried using others as well.

Comment: Hmmm. One thing I'm pretty sure about (like ~98.7%) is that you're not having an issue with MVC per-say, but you're having an issue with your DataContext, which I'm assuming in LINQ to SQL, so at the least you may want to add a *linq-to-sql* tag on your post so that someone with a bit more knowledge can try to help you out on it.

Comment: @dcolumbus - is the string you want actually in the web.config or your Data project's config settings?

Comment: Does that connection string have to be in both projects Web.config?

Comment: The connection string has to be in the *root* Web.config at the minimum.